# Cannot use docker-compose with gulp-webserver

Tags: docker, gulp, docker-compose

I'm trying to use `gulp-webserver` with Docker but I cannot get web pages from the host system

I have this `Docker` file

```
FROM node:8

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

COPY gulpfile.js .

RUN npm install -g gulp
RUN npm install gulp

# Run when the container launches
CMD ["gulp"]
```

I use it with a `docker-compose.yml` file like this one:

```
  web:
    container_name: "web"
    build: ./web/
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - "./web/src:/usr/src/app/src"
```

All looks fine. Indeed, in the log I see:

```
web         | [18:06:08] Webserver started at http://localhost:3000
web         | [18:06:08] Finished 'serve' after 8.08 ms
web         | [18:06:08] Starting 'watch'...
web         | [18:06:08] Finished 'watch' after 78 ms
web         | [18:06:08] Starting 'default'...
web         | [18:06:08] Finished 'default' after 2.85 μs
```

If I call `curl localhost:3000` **inside the container** I get my page. However, I cannot reach http://localhost:3000 from the host system.

What is it going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that my problem was related to the configuration of `gulp-webserver`. Indeed, in order to reach the server from the host network you need to set the [`host`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-webserver#options) option to `'0.0.0.0'`. E.g.,

```
gulp.task('webserver', function() {
  gulp.src('app')
    .pipe(webserver({
      port: 3000,
      livereload: true,
      host: '0.0.0.0'
    }));
});
```